# onEdit trigger causes updated date to be returned as a number

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I currently have a Google script bound to my spreadsheet using an onEdit trigger to allow multiple dropdowns.

However, it is affecting my columns with dates, changing them from date format "DD/MM/YYYY" to a 5-digit number

Please let me know what I need to add to the script to stop the format from changing to Automatic.

Also, my code isn't great, I had to copy and paste and play with it to make it work, and I didn't know how to apply it to specific ranges on specific sheets, so applies to all of them.  I don't know if this is causing my issue.

To note, the date columns on each sheet are different (Sheet 1 is Column 16 and 17, Sheet 2 is 6, etc.)

My Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4,5,6,7,9,10,11,18 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet 4") {

      newValue=e.value;
      oldValue=e.oldValue;

      if(!e.value) {
      
        activeCell.setValue(""); 
      
      } else {

        if (!e.oldValue) {

          activeCell.setValue(newValue);

        } else {

          activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);

        }

     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Dates are numbers, simply apply the preferred date format explicitly to the column in question instead of leaving it as automatic.

Answer (score 0):

For the date issue, explicitly apply a 'Date' number format to the column.  Don't leave it as 'Automatic'.

For the sheet name and column tests, see the following example script.  You can replace the actions with your own.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const name = sheet.getName();
  const col = range.getColumn();
  const row = range.getRow();

  const columns = [ 
    { Name: "Sheet1", Nums: [16, 17] },
    { Name: "Sheet2", Nums: [6] }
  ];
  
  const i = columns.findIndex(c => c.Name === name);
  
  if ((i > -1) && (columns[i].Nums.indexOf(col) > -1)) {

    sheet.getRange(row, col).setValue("✅");

  } else {

    sheet.getRange(row, col).setValue("❌");

  }

}
```